# Redhat Shellscript Displaying "count" of files modified in the last 5 days

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I am trying to display the count/number of files that was saved/modified last 5 days. In other words, I just need to know the count of 5-day old messages.

I searched google and it talks about using `find`

For me, I would like to use `ls` command.
I am able to count using `ls | wc -l` but that does not exclude/filter files by age(last modified)

I tried `-mtime +5` or `-ctime +5` but still can't get it right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the count of files modified in the last 5 days (understood  as last 120 hours) starting from the root directory `/`, I would try:

```
find / -type f -mtime -5 | wc -l
```

The command `wc -l` counts the number of lines of output. Error messages are not included in that count.

If you want to limit your search to a part of the tree structure, v.gr. your `$HOME` directory, change `/` by `$HOME`.

If you have symlinks in your tree structure, you will need to add some options like `-L` to the `find` command